# Knockout: How do I preserve table cell order?

Tags: knockout.js

I have this fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/tvwxyz/1ju0vng1/5/

```
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myValue, click: myAction" />
<table id="tb1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">a1</td>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>a3</td>
        <td>a4</td>
        <td>a5</td>
        <td>a6</td>
        <td rowspan="2">a7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>b2</td>
        <td>b3</td>
        <td>b4</td>
        <td>b5</td>
        <td>b6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div data-bind="text: myValue"></div>

var viewModel = {
    myValue: ko.observable(false),
    myAction: function() {
        if($("#cb1").prop("checked")){
            $("#tb1 tr:first td").hide();
            $("#tb1 tr:first td:first").show();
            $("#tb1 tr:first td:last").show();
        }else{
            $("#tb1 tr:first td").show();
        }
       return true;
    }    
};
```

When the page loads, you can see the A1 and A7 cells span both rows.
Clicking the checkbox hides A2-A6 (which is what I want) but A7 is no longer in its original position.

How do I preserve the original table cell order when hiding inner cells?

Comment: In a very real sense, the cell order *is* preserved. A7 is the first cell after A1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [edited your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ju0vng1/8/) to act in a more Knockout way and do what (I think) you want. I inserted an empty colspan=5 cell that is visible only when the A cells are hidden.

```
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myValue" />

<table id="tb1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">a1</td>
        <td data-bind="visible:myValue" colspan=5></td>
        <td data-bind="visible:!myValue()">a2</td>
        <td data-bind="visible:!myValue()">a3</td>
        <td data-bind="visible:!myValue()">a4</td>
        <td data-bind="visible:!myValue()">a5</td>
        <td data-bind="visible:!myValue()">a6</td>
        <td rowspan="2">a7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b2</td>
        <td>b3</td>
        <td>b4</td>
        <td>b5</td>
        <td>b6</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div data-bind="text: myValue"></div>
```

The HTML is a little cumbersome, but the Javascript gets very simple:

```
var viewModel = {
    myValue: ko.observable(false),
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```